# One to One video call between Ai and User

Tags: reactjs, openai-api, gpt-3, videochat, videosdk.live

I am developing an application that facilitates video chat between users and an AI (GPT model). The typical architecture of this app is as follows: I am utilizing [VideoSDK-React](https://docs.videosdk.live/react/guide/video-and-audio-calling-api-sdk/concept-and-architecture) for the video call service. I need to connect this service with a Node.js server in order to transmit audio (questions asked by the user) to the AI and relay the AI's responses back to the user.

[image]

I tried with creating singnaling server from scratch but the main functionality of project is to integrate gpt model as a one peer so decide to go with third party service sdk.